# Garbage Collection (Local references)

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, jvm

I have confusions on how GC works in Java.

Below is the code snippet that confuse me:

```
private Data data = new Data();

void main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
       MyThread thread = new MyThread(data);
       thread.start();
    }

    System.gc();

    // Long running process

} 

class MyThread extends Thread {
    private Data dataReference;

    MyThread(Data data) {
        dataReference = data;
    }
}
```

In the above example if **gc** is called before continuing further (// Long running process)

- will the local threads will be garbage collected?
- Or GC will mark them (MyThread local references) as alive since it holds the reference to global reference ***data***?

Comment: GC 101 - it is non deterministic; you cannot say for certain that something will or will not be collected. GC 101 - a live `Thread` is a GC root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MyThread` instances may be garbage collected only after they are done (i.e. their `run` method is done). After the for loop ends, any instances of `MyThread` whose `run` method is done may be garbage collected (since there are no references to them).

The fact the the `MyThread` instances each hold a reference to a `Data` instance that doesn't get garbage collected doesn't affect the time the `MyThread` instances become eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what you are saying is, when threads are done with execution it is eligible for GC irrespective of references it is holding inside. (Am i correct ??)

Comment: @NKR yes. As long as it is running, it cannot be garbage collected. Once it is done running, the same rules as any other reference types apply - only if there exist references to the MyThread instance (for example, if your main method had a `List<MyThread>` holding references to all the created `MyThread`s), it cannot be garbage collected. The fact that it holds a reference to an instance that cannot be garbage collected doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. This was troubling me for a long time. I accepted your answer.

Comment: can you suggest me some useful links that explains Garbage collection (java) in depth and detail?

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyThread` instances will not be eligible for garbage collection until they have finished running.

The thread stack and local variables for any live (i.e. started but not terminated) thread are reachable by definition.

> A *reachable* object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.  ([JLS 12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1))

Furthermore, since a live thread could call `Thread.currentThread()`, the thread's `Thread` object must also be reachable as long as the thread is live ... irrespective of any other references to it.

However, if the reference to a `Thread` object becomes unreachable *before* the `start()` method has been called, it *will* be eligible for garbage collection.   If this was not so, creating and not starting a `Thread` would be a memory leak!

Answer (score 1):

You can always call to the garbage collection and but it is not guaranteed to run at the same time. (may or may not depending on your system). because garbage collection running under the daemon thread which is a low priority thread.

An object becomes eligible for Garbage collection or GC if it's not reachable from any live threads or by any static references. In other words, you can say that an object becomes eligible for garbage collection if its all references are null. Cyclic dependencies are not counted as the reference so if object A has a reference to object B and object B has a reference to Object A and they don't have any other live reference then both Objects A and B will be eligible for Garbage collection.

[garbage-collection-in-java](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no grantee that a gc will be executed after a `System.gc();` call. A `System.gc()` call simply SUGGESTS that the VM do a garbage collection.

And `thread` is not the target for a gc. A thread won't be cleaned up unless its finished running.

Generally speaking, objects are juedged to be alive, if they are still referenced by others.

Answer (score 0):

You should never be calling System.gc.  The system will call it for you when low on memory.

In Java, GC works on a system called Mark and Sweep.  The algorithm works like this

- Start with a set of root objects (GC roots) and a set of all the objects allocated.
- Mark those roots
- Mark every object reachable from those roots, by visiting every field of these objects recursively.
- When every possible object is marked, walk the list of all objects.  If an item is not marked, free it.

(This is a simplification, the modern implementation works sort of like this, but is far more sophisticated).

So what is a GC root?  Any object stored in a local variable still in scope, in a static variable, in a JNI reference, and all threads that are currently running.

So no, a thread won't be cleaned up unless its finished running.  That's why threads so easily create a memory leak-  as long as they run, any object they have a reference to cannot be freed because a GC root (the thread) has a reference to it.

But the relationship always goes down from the root to other objects.  If Foo holds a reference to Bar, Foo can be deleted regardless of if Bar can be.  But if Foo can't be deleted, then neither can Bar.